# How to use return value of one program as input for another?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I know that I can use pipes to set the output stream of one program to input for another:

`bigNumber | factors`

But what if I want to simply feed the returned value from `bigNumber`'s main function as `factors`'s input rather than what `bigNumber` echos to the output stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bigNumber
echo $? | factors
```

Most Unix/Linux shells make the exit value available in the variable `$?`.

Answer (score 1):

The error code returned by the last executed program is available in the $? shell variable